Proving concavity of the Lagrange dual function
The Lagrange dual function for an optimization problem of form
$$\min f_0(\boldsymbol x)\quad\text{subject to}\quad f_i(\boldsymbol x)\le0,h_j(\boldsymbol x)=0\quad i=1,2\dots m,j=1,2,\dots p$$
with domain $D$, is defined as
$$g(\boldsymbol\lambda,\boldsymbol\nu)=\inf_{\boldsymbol x\in D}\left(f_0(\boldsymbol x)+\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_if_i(\boldsymbol x)+\sum_{j=1}^p\nu_jh_j(\boldsymbol x)\right)$$
Consider 2 points $(\boldsymbol \lambda_1,\boldsymbol \nu_1),(\boldsymbol \lambda_2,\boldsymbol \nu_2)$. Let $C_1=g(\boldsymbol \lambda_1,\boldsymbol \nu_1)$ and $C_2=g(\boldsymbol \lambda_2,\boldsymbol \nu_2)$. A point between them is of the form $(t\boldsymbol \lambda_1+(1-t)\boldsymbol\lambda_2,t\boldsymbol \nu_1+(1-t)\boldsymbol\nu_2)$ with corresponding Langrage dual value $g(t\boldsymbol \lambda_1+(1-t)\boldsymbol\lambda_2,t\boldsymbol \nu_1+(1-t)\boldsymbol\nu_2)$.
Since $g$ is the pointwise infimum of a family of affine functions of $(\boldsymbol \lambda,\boldsymbol \nu)$, we have for any fixed $\boldsymbol x$
$$g(t\boldsymbol \lambda_1+(1-t)\boldsymbol\lambda_2,t\boldsymbol \nu_1+(1-t)\boldsymbol\nu_2)\ge tg(\boldsymbol\lambda_1,\boldsymbol\nu_1)+(1-t)g(\boldsymbol\lambda_2,\boldsymbol\nu_2)$$
which proves that $g$ is a concave curve.
Is this correct?

Is it Deja Vu or someone really asked a similar question a few days ago?

@PNDas Just saw it too, but their confusion is regarding the differences in definition.

You have the right intuition. Just remember that, for $t \in (0,1)$, $g$ is concave if:
$$g(tx + (1-t)y) \geq tg(x) + (1-t)g(y), $$
and if $g_1, g_2$ are affine functions and $g(x)=\min\{g_1(x),g_2(x)\}$, then:
\begin{array}
&g(\alpha x)&=\min\{g_1(\alpha x),g_2(\alpha x)\}\\
&\geq \min\{\alpha g_1(x),\alpha g_2(x)\}\\
& \geq \alpha \min \{g_1(x),g_2(x)\} \\
& = \alpha g(x)
\end{array}
Also, you need to define that $t$ is in the interval $(0,1)$ and for fixed $t$ (not $x$ as you mentioned) the inequality defining concavity holds.
